# xcode: How to connect intruments Leaks tool with simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I want to detect if there are memory leaks in my application. But the problem is that when I click to red button it show a window to chose executable, but I do not know how to point instrument's leak utility to my iphone Simulator application.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Xcode goto product > Profile, then select leaks.